# $a^b+2$ or $a^b-2$ is in set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite set of positive integers. For any two $a,b\in A$, $a\neq b$, at least one of the numbers $a^b+2$ and $a^b-2$ are also  in $A$. Must $A$ contain a composite number?

Comment: what is a composite number?

Comment: a composite number is an integer larger than one, which is not prime.

Comment: Note that if $A$ does not contain a composite number then all $a$ must be odd.

Comment: @Arian,if I understood the problem correctly,all b must also be odd(since a and b play a symmetric role).

Comment: It is interesting to note that this is false in the finite case, let $A=\{1,3\}$

Comment: The answer is almost surely "yes", right?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{P}_{2}$ be the set of twin prime numbers. If there are two prime numbers $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $p_{1}^{p_2} \pm 2$ is in  $\mathbb{P}_{2}$ and repeating the process, considering this new number,  you obtain always numbers in $\mathbb{P}_{2}$, then $A$ does not need contain composite numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Take four odd numbers $a<b<c<d$ from the set, all greater than $3$, such that $c=b^a\pm2$ and $d=c^b\pm2$.

Case 1: $c=b^a\pm2$ and $d=c^b\pm2$ (with equal signs).

Then $c=b^a\pm2\equiv b\pm2 \pmod3$ and $d=c^b\pm2\equiv c\pm2 \pmod3$. One of $b,c,d$ is divisible by $3$.

Case 2: $c=b^a\pm2$ and $d=c^b\mp2$ (with opposite signs).
If $b$ is a prime then, by Fermat's theorem,
$$
d = c^b \mp2 \equiv c\mp2 = b^a \equiv 0 \pmod{b}
$$
so $d$ is divisible by $b$. (Obviously $d$ is greater than $b$.)